# The difference between empty node and a node with 0 value

Tags: xml, xslt

Trying to learn XSL, I can't get it straight in my head.
Say, I want to make an XSLT template that processes nodes based on their value. Let's make a sample situation:

```
<data>
  <item1>0</item1>
  <item2></item2>
  <!--Multiple similar nodes below-->
</data>
```

Let's try to mark empty ones with `xsi:nil="true"`, while leaving the zero ones be:

```
<xsl:template match="node()[starts-with(name(), 'item')]">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:if test="not(node()) and not(.!='')"><!--This is the problem-->
      <xsl:attribute name="xsi:nil">true</xsl:attribute>
    </xsl:if>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

That does do exactly what I want it to do, but that is a Frankenstein's monster code which I don't fully understand yet.

Now, while experimenting, researching stackoverflow and trying to figure it out, I found out that `not(node())` may define both empty and zero value nodes, as well as `.!=0`, yet `.!=''` seems to target only zero value nodes, which doesn't make any sense to me.
It seems to me as string values may be qualified as a zero value, or zero values as empty string values, but I can't figure it out past that.

Basically, the question is **how can I distinguish an empty node from a node with a zero value**?

Comment: Found a mistake in the example XSL code, it works now as it is supposed to, but the nature of the question remains the same.

Comment: "*I found out that not(node()) may define both empty and zero value nodes*" I don't think so.

Comment: You're absolutely right, I was confused because my code was faulty and did not produce the results I expected it did. Thank you for pointing it out!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> it does add xsi:nil="true" to an empty node, yet it for whatever
>   reason removes the item1 value of a zero, making it empty.

That's because you have placed the instruction:

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
```

within the `xsl:if` statement.

> Basically, the question is **how can I distinguish an empty node from a
>   node with a zero value?**

An empty node has no child nodes - elements, text nodes or any other node type (except attributes). A node with a zero value has a child text node with the string value of "0". To test for empty elements, it is sufficient to do:

```
<xsl:template match="*[starts-with(name(), 'item')][not(node())]">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:attribute name="xsi:nil">true</xsl:attribute>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Thank you, Michael, that clarifies most of the stuff I did not understand on that matter; as for the mistake in the example, I've already found it, but thank you for pointing it out. Can you please also explain to me what `.!=''` represents and why does it work in the case presented above?

Comment: Oh, nevermind, I got it - that did not work at all, but the first expression worked. And if I wanted to process only nodes with zero values, I should have used `test=".='0'"` instead. Thank you, I think I get it now.